# how can i create dynamic json data to hit my rest client

Tags: mysql, etl, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I'm a beginner in data integration tool `Pentaho`.

My data base table hase all columns together. Now I want to create a JSON from that table data in order to hit my REST client.

My REST client accepts JSON like this, so I need to prepare the same.

```
{
 "firstName" : "xyz",
  "lastName" : "sdf",
  "birthDate" : "1977-07-07",
  "email" : "hj@dev4life.com",
  "phones" : [ {
    "number" : "123456",
    "phoneType" : "PRIMARY"
  } ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify, what is your question?

Comment: Hi @Dmitriy Popov  my question is like you have you have some data in your table eg name: employee with no relations
employee_name 
employee_addresline1
employee_city
employee_pincode

if i'm using directly jsoninput option by pentaho the the I'm getting json like this

{"data":[{"employee_name" :"sam",
"employee_addresline1": "CB-124 street lory",
"employee_city":"NY",
"employee_pincode":"15585"}]}

Comment: I can use data value to hot my rest client however i need json like this 

{"employee_name" :"sam",
"address":{
"employee_addresline1": "CB-124 street lory",
"employee_city":"NY",
"employee_pincode":"15585"}
}

Comment: For complex JSON structures you're better off using Modified Java Script Value step. Just be careful on using For iterators in Pentaho Javascript, they work the same, but they don't 'perform' the same.

Comment: Hi, If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there with the **`JSON Output`** step. the problem is that **JSON Output** step doesn't handle nested data structures well, so you might want to handle `phones` and the other information separately and then merge the results.

Below is an example KTR to handle your task:

[image]

---

### JSON Output step: process phones

In the first JSON Output step, set up the following
[image]

under `Fields Tab`, add two fields: `number` and `phoneType`. The new field `phones` after this step is:

```
{"phones":[{"number":123456.0,"phoneType":"PRIMARY"}]}
```

---

### JSON Output step:

do the similar to the above step except the following:

> - In **General** tab, set *Json bloc name* = `data`, *Output Value* = `outputValue`
> - In **Fields** tab, add the fields `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthDate` and `email`

The new field called `outputValue` added from this step is:

```
{"data":[{"firstName":"himanshi","lastName":"joshi","birthDate":"1997-07-24","email":"hj@test.com"}]}
```

**Note:** you should not retrieve and add phones into the JSON output here since the nested data structure will become a single String value in the final output.

---

### JSON Input step: retrieve $.data[0]

As labelled in the Step name, we use JSON Input step to retrieve $.data[0] from the field `outputValue`, so it becomes:

```
{"firstName":"himanshi","lastName":"joshi","birthDate":"1997-07-24","email":"hj@test.com"}
```

> - In **File** tab: select `Source is from a previous step` and *Select field* = `outputValue`
> - In **Fields** tab, add a new field: *Name* = `rest_client_data` and *Path* = `$.data[0]`

---

### Replace in string step: merge phones

Use the `Replace in string` step to merge two JSON strings: `phones` and `rest_client_data`.
[image]

Basically, it replaces the leading brace `{` of phones with a `comma` and then replaces the trailing `}` of rest_client_data with the updated `phones`

---

### Select values step

To keep only the needed field: `rest_client_data`

```
{"firstName":"himanshi","lastName":"joshi","birthDate":"1997-07-24","email":"hj@test.com","phones":[{"number":123456.0,"phoneType":"PRIMARY"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to create JSON from a tabular data structure is via the Javascript step. JSON input is meant to work the other way around: given a JSON data field, extract individual values.